# Unable to use parity_codec's Encode even though I have derived it for a struct

Tags: rust, traits

I am trying to use [`Encode::encode`](https://docs.rs/parity-codec/4.1.0/parity_codec/trait.Encode.html) on structs with a derived implementation, but I am getting this error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `encode` found for type `AnimalCollection<Animal>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:42:57
   |
13 | struct AnimalCollection<A: AnimalTrait> {
   | --------------------------------------- method `encode` not found for this
...
42 |     println!("animal collection encoded = {:?}",animals.encode());
   |                                                         ^^^^^^
   |
   = note: the method `encode` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `AnimalCollection<Animal> : _IMPL_DECODE_FOR_Animal::_parity_codec::Encode`
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
   = note: the following trait defines an item `encode`, perhaps you need to implement it:
           candidate #1: `_IMPL_DECODE_FOR_Animal::_parity_codec::Encode`
```

This is the code:

```
use indexmap::map::IndexMap;
use parity_codec;
use parity_codec::{Decode, Encode};

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Encode, Decode, Debug)]
struct Animal {
    name: String,
    cell: u32,
}

trait AnimalTrait: Encode + Decode {}

impl AnimalTrait for Animal {}

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Encode, Decode, Debug)]
struct AnimalCollection<A: AnimalTrait> {
    animals: IndexMap<String, A>,
}

impl<A: AnimalTrait> AnimalCollection<A> {
    fn new() -> AnimalCollection<A> {
        AnimalCollection {
            animals: IndexMap::new(),
        }
    }

    fn add(&mut self, name: String, a: A) {
        self.animals.insert(name, a);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Animal {
        name: String::from("Tiger"),
        cell: 10,
    };
    println!("animal struct encoded = {:?}", a.encode());
    let mut animals = AnimalCollection::<Animal>::new();
    animals.add(
        String::from("Dog"),
        Animal {
            name: String::from("Dog"),
            cell: 1,
        },
    );
    animals.add(
        String::from("Cat"),
        Animal {
            name: String::from("Cat"),
            cell: 2,
        },
    );
    println!("animal collection encoded = {:?}", animals.encode());
}
```

Why isn't it working despite that I have `#[derive]`d all the traits automatically? How do I fix it?

Since I am deriving the `Encode` and `Decode` traits, I shouldn't really implement anything on my own, or should I?

I tested this code and it works on the `Animal` struct but doesn't work on the `AnimalCollection` struct. I also tried to implement the `Encode` trait on `AnimalCollection` but immediately got "conflicting implementation" error, so I am kind of stuck on how to solve this.

`Cargo.toml` is a bit tricky, you need to use `derive` feature:

```
[package]
name = "encmap"
version = "0.0.1"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
parity-codec = { version = "3.3", features = ["derive"] }
indexmap = "1.0.2"
```

Comment: Does `indexmap::IndexMap` implement `parity_codec::Encode`? These are unrelated crates that don't seem to know about each other.

Comment: Using `cargo expand`, you will notice that `#[derive(Encode)]` generates `impl<A: AnimalTrait> Encode for AnimalCollection<A> where IndexMap<String, A>: Encode`.

Comment: The error message is surprisingly bad though.

Comment: @mcarton, yeah, they are unrelated crates, and you have a point here, I don't think `IndexMap` is implementing `Encode` trait, but shouldn't `parity_codec` do this kind of job?

Comment: No, a derive macro can only implement a trait for the type it is applied to.

Comment: @mcarton , so what could be the workaround for this situation ?

Comment: Implement the trait yourself rather than deriving it. You won't be able to call `self.animals.encode()` because that doesn't exist, so you'll have to decide on how you want to serialize this field yourself.